# How to monitor mnesia load?

Tags: erlang, monitoring, mnesia

I sometimes get `mnesia overloaded` error message while using primarily `async_dirty` queries and `ram_copies` tables. So to understand what is going on I want to get more information about mnesia state such as number of queries per second or the size of query queue. I've searched a lot and found two probable approaches.

The first is [`mnesia:system_info`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#system_info-1) function that can return a list of current transactions. But it seems not able to provide an information about non-transactional queries.

The second is subscribing to [mnesia events](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/Mnesia_chap5.html#id76682), but using this way some active background processing is needed as well as manual subscribing to each table events.

Are there better ways of getting this information?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what kind of information you want? This is not entirely clear.

Comment: @IGIVECRAPANSWERS, any information about query execution rate. It may be the number of elementry reads/writes performed within last second. Also it may be the number of elementary reads/writes queued but not finished.

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the most direct answer, and I'm not as familiar with the code as I was four years ago, but I once had the same question and made an erlang app that monitors mnesia write statistics serves an SVG graph of throughput:

[Mnesia Graphs](https://github.com/woahdae/mnesia_graphs/)

If it's sort of something you want, the tests exercise the functionality: https://github.com/woahdae/mnesia_graphs/blob/master/test/mnesia_graphs_srv_tests.erl

If it's *really* something you want, I could take a second look at the project. I'm working in Erlang again, so it's a good exercise.

Also, yet another reminder of who a good README is for: yourself, four years later!

Comment: Ok. It looks like there are no way to avoid active monitoring. Thanks for the answer.  I'll look at your code.

Answer (score 0):

In default it limits with 4.
You have to change dc_dump_limit from 4 to 50 or something.
 Than it  will work for you.

Comment: `dc_dump_limit` controls how often `disc_copies` tables are dumped from memory. In my case it won't help because I have no `disc_copies` tables. Anyway the question is how to measure this "load" which causes  overloading.

Comment: -mnesia dc_dump_limit Number

and 
(Log) > (filesize(Tab)/
Dc_dump_limit)

its a  configuration parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Before 16 Erlang
`1> appmon:start().` 
After you need to use 
`1> observer:start().`
For all times you need 32bit [WxWidget](http://www.wxwidgets.org/downloads/)

Last two years we are using [Folsomite Erlang event capture](https://github.com/campanja/folsomite) and for triggering and visualisation for captured events and metrics we are using [Icinga](https://www.icinga.com) and [Graphite](https://graphiteapp.org)